# How to control size of texture for Node with an Image in Quick3d?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick3d

I'm experimenting with QtQuick3D on Qt 5.15. It's feature to embed QtQuick `Item`s is quite awesome. I like to create a rectangle (100 x 100 units) and fill it with an `Image` (1000 x 1000 pixels).

That works nice when I define a `Material` and assign it (see Model `okButCodeSpread`, right rectangle in screenshot), but its more to code.

Its a lot shorter to define a `Node` and embed an `Image`. However, I struggle to control the size of the texture in this case. Whatever I try, it's blurry. See Model `doesNotWork` and left rectangle in screenshot.

I found a work around by scaling the `Image` up and the `Node` down. See Model `okButUgly`, middle rectangle in screenshot.

Any ideas who to get a crisp texture for Model `doesNotWork`?

Also, how can hide the image in 2D used to define the `Material`? Setting in visible property to false causes the texture in 3D to be solid black...

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick3D 1.15
import QtQuick3D.Helpers 1.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Image {
        id: image   
        layer.enabled: true
        width: 1000
        height: 1000
        source: "test.png"
    }

    View3D {
        id: view
        width: 400
        height: 400
        renderMode: View3D.Inline

        environment: SceneEnvironment {
            clearColor: "dimgray"
            backgroundMode: SceneEnvironment.Color
        }

        PerspectiveCamera {
            id: cam
            position: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 350)
        }

        DirectionalLight {
        }

        WasdController {
            controlledObject: cam
        }

        DefaultMaterial {
            id: mat
            diffuseMap: Texture {
                sourceItem: image
            }
        }

        Node {
            id: doesNotWork
            position: Qt.vector3d(-150, 0, 0)

            Image {
                layer.enabled: true
                layer.textureSize: Qt.size(1000, 1000)
                sourceSize: Qt.size(1000, 1000)
                width: 100
                height: 100
                source: "test.png"
           }
        }

        Node {
            id: okButUgly        
            property real scaleFactor: 10
            position: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
            scale: Qt.vector3d(1/scaleFactor, 1/scaleFactor , 1/scaleFactor)

            Image {
                width: 100 * okButUgly.scaleFactor
                height: 100 * okButUgly.scaleFactor           
                source: "test.png"
            }
        }

        Model {
            id: okButCodeSpread
            position: Qt.vector3d(150, 0, 0)
            source: "#Rectangle"
            materials: mat
        }
    }

    DebugView {
        source: view
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]